# RESTful API post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, encode

I am making a request to an API, I'm using basic authorization, yet for some reason the API is unable to decode the authorization string

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
import base64,requests
from base64 import b64encode

url = 'api.sample/test'

APIuser = b'generic_user'
APIpass = b'generic_pass'

myobj = {"data1_field":"data1"}

data_string = APIuser + b":" + APIpass
data_bytes = b64encode(data_string).decode('ascii')

head = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'*/*','Authorization':'Basic ' + data_bytes}

x = requests.post(url, headers=head,
        data = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "detail": "Cannot decode: java.io.StringReader@45fab9",
    "message": "Exception while reading request"
  },
  "status": "failure"
}
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: update i found fix on this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289682/exception-while-reading-request-detail-cannot-decode-java-io-stringreade.
im not getting the java error, but now im getting an error that i could not authentica in the API, and the key is being printed correctly

Comment: I think i found the root cause but i dont know how to fix it:
API requires to have the data sent on base64 encoded, and the data im sending is a string. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

B64 is read as a byte data on python, so the string will be represented as b'x', so the way of doing it is sending the encryption type on the response, also i was using ascii encoding, and the required one is utf8, important not to mistake it with utf-8 (apparently not the same for the compiler)

```
url = "api.sample/test"

payload = "{\"Data1\": \"Data1_field\"}

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic get the string'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```